# Angular SSR - Lazy loading does not change the server side main.js file size

Tags: angular, angular-universal

1. I am using Angular Universal (version 12) to create server & browser side code
2. My main.js was too big (6Mb). To reduce the main.js bundle size - converted most of the modules into lazy loading.
3. My SSR build gives me 2 folders

--browser

----en

------**main.js => reduced drastically to 1MB**

------Many other small chunks

--server

----en

--------**main.js => still 6MB**

------many other small chunks

4. For SSR I run as below:

   ```
    pm2 server/en/main.js
   ```
5. Issue is - now my site (without SSR) is very fast but through SSR it's slow. (I need SSR mainly for Google SEO / Social media)
6. Browser build:

   ```
     "prodtemplate": {
          "localize": ["en"],
          "fileReplacements": [
            {
              "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
              "with": "src/environments/environment.prodtemplate.ts"
            }
          ],
          "aot": true,
          "optimization": true,
          "outputHashing": "all",
          "sourceMap": false,
          "namedChunks": false,
          "extractLicenses": true,
          "vendorChunk": true,
          "commonChunk": true,
          "buildOptimizer": true,
          "budgets": [
            {
              "type": "initial",
              "maximumWarning": "2mb",
              "maximumError": "5mb"
            },
            {
              "type": "anyComponentStyle",
              "maximumWarning": "6kb",
              "maximumError": "10kb"
            }
          ]
        },
   ```
7. Server build

   ```
      "prodtemplate": {
          "localize": ["en"],
          "fileReplacements": [
            {
              "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
              "with": "src/environments/environment.prodtemplate.ts"
            }
          ],
          "optimization": true,
          "outputHashing": "media",
          "sourceMap": false,
          "namedChunks": false,
          "extractLicenses": true
        },
   ```

I was expecting that even server side main.js should get reduced in size. Is this a wrong assumption? Am I missing anything?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think this is correct. I guess if you'd remove the browser build, the server build won't work anymore. I'm using ASP.NET Core and in my case the SSR is broken if the browser build is inside **ClientApp/dist/browser** instead of **ClientApp/dist**, even though nothing else changed. My assumption is that the main.server.js only contains the bootstrapping code, which consumes the rest of your javascript bundles.

Comment: So is there any way to reduce sever side main.js file size? 6MB is too big

Comment: Why does it matter how big the main.server.js bundle is? It's never sent to the client! It never needs to go over the internet. NodeJS reads and executes the file which triggers the BootModule...